# Quotient Modules of finite rank module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a free module of finite rank. Let $S$ and $T$ be free submodules of $M$. Prove that if $S$ and $T$ are isomorphic, then $M/S$ and $M/T$ are isomorphic.

My partial answer:

Since $S$ and $T$ are isomorphic, we have a isomorphism $\sigma: S \rightarrow T$. Define $f:M/S \rightarrow M/T$ by $f(m+S)=\begin{cases}  \sigma(m)+T, \text{ if } m\in S 
\\ \sigma^{-1}(m)+T, \text{ if } m\in T \\
m+T, \text{ if } m\in M \backslash (S \cup T) 
\end{cases}$
Verify that $f$ is a isomorphsm.

Comment: This isn't true. Take $M=\mathbb{Z}$, and $S=2\mathbb{Z}$, and $T=4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Define $f: M \rightarrow M/T$ by $f(m)=2m+T$ if $m\in S$ and $f(m)=m+T$ if $m \in M \backslash S$, then we have $f$ is a homomorphism with $ker(f)=S$, so $M/S$ and $M/T$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Functions which are defined by case distinction are almost never homomorphisms. And the counterexample by Alex is, of course, correct. For $n > 0$ the group $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ has exactly $n$ elements. Hence $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $n=m$. This provides many counterexamples to the claim, already when all the ranks are $1$.